# What did Robin Hobb call a group of dragons?

Tags: dragons, realm-of-the-elderlings, robin-hobb

Robin Hobb towards the end of the "Realm of the Elderlings" series called a group of dragons something and I can't for the life of me remember what it was or find it in said books or online. Anyone know what it was?

Comment: You mean, like a pack, a flock or something, or more "the five of Kelsingra"-sounding? (Read those a long time ago, but I don't remember such a thing)

Comment: exactly like a pack or flock, or something, but she had a specific word for it that fit remarkably well.

Comment: @Jenayah The word you & NaturesCreed are looking for is [***collective noun***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun) *a la* a parliament of owls, a clowder of cats, a whatever of teenagers, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### A Catastrophe

> His eyes on the dragons and their destruction, Beloved asked, ‘If a flock of crows is a murder, what should we call a group of dragons?’ ‘A catastrophe of dragons,’ someone said, with no humour in his deep voice.
>
> <sub>*Assassin's Fate - Chapter 39: The Vengeance*</sub>

Comment: That's the one! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

### A Tangle

> One at a time, the other great serpents heaved their long bodies free of clinging muck and outgrown skin *[...]* joining in the tangle's dance.
>   <sub>*Ship of Magic - Prologue: The Tangle*</sub>

> Almost immediately, she sensed that the ship did not wish her to be there but She Who Remembers felt no compunction about remaining. Her duty was to the tangle of serpents she had awakened. If the ship were a danger to them, she would discover it.
>   <sub>*Ship of Destiny - Chapter 15: Serpent Ship*</sub>

> Maulkin is the leader of a tangle of serpents. His tangle is the last one, and the only tangle who makes it up the river to start the process of turning into a dragon.
>   <sub>[Maulkin](https://robinhobbelderlings.fandom.com/wiki/Maulkin)</sub>

Comment: No not what I'm after, this is for Serpents but not Dragons. It was only mentioned once, late in the series by either I think either Thymara or Elise.

Answer (score 1):

In Blood of dragons, a sailor from Chalced called them a **Flock** when a group of dragons attacks their boats.  While not mentioned by Thymara or Elise, it is mentioned toward the end of the **Rain Wild Chronicles**, if not the end of the full **Realm of the Elderling** series.  I'm listening to the audio book, so i can only state it occurs roughly in the middle of the book, somewhere about halfway though CD 7 of 13.